# jQuery load not executing on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Pardon me for asking such a basic question, I'm not a UI guy. Tried to google few things but not able to relate to my case.

I have following code

```
var img = new Image();
var imageUrl = "some API which will get me the image";

$(img).attr('src', imageUrl).load(function() {
    imageLoaded = true;             # line A
});
```

I am assuming that the `attr` function will assign the attribute to the `img` variable, and later will register the anonymous function passed to `load` to be executed whenever the image is loaded successfully. (correct me if I'm wrong)

I'm trying to debug this using developer tools. On Chrome 52 the *line A* is not getting hit. On Chrome 51, and Firefox 45 it's getting hit properly. Because of this line, my application is not working.

I'm using `jQuery 2.3.1`

Any idea why this might be failing? Am I missing something?

Comment: It's a good idea to set up the "load" handler *before* you set the "src" attribute.

Comment: You're lucky, a lot of times people make this mistake but never see it break due to it not being cached yet.

Comment: Hey @Pointy thanks for the comment. I agree, probably I need to change this. but the thing is I need to give some strong reason to change this. Need to make sure this is the issue that is causing the problem

Comment: @KevinB could you be more specific and point me some articles which explains this. 

I'm actually not sure whether this is causing any issue, if yes why now on Chrome 52?

Comment: If you set the attribute before binding the load event and the image is cached, the load event might not get called. If you do it in the opposite order, it will always get called.

Comment: @KevinB Okay. I understood now. Is this thing browser specific? It's happening only on `Chrome 52` and not any other browser including `Chrome 51`

Comment: Not exactly, but, browser implementations may differ resulting in slightly different results. For all I know the browser vendors may have coded around this problem by now. best to code it correctly on your end to begin with anyway though.

Comment: @KevinB Yes. I understand that, but I need some *sure* way to say that this is causing some problem. I just checked, it's working fine Chrome 53 beta.

Comment: Do research. this is a VERY common problem, and was much more of a problem ~ 4 years ago than it is today. Look at how all reputable image preloading scripts work, they set the onload event first. all of them do. if they don't they're doing it wrong.

Comment: browsers "should" fire the event both ways, but they don't always. you should use the option that makes it always work.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign src after the api has resolved.

Comment: No. That won't solve the purpose. The reason it is written this way to do "something" after the image has been loaded. So this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Either you have the image url or the url is going to be fetched by the api call, in the first case the load event for image element will work, but for the later it wont and you need to listen to load/done/success event of the api call

Comment: The thing that bothers me is work on few browsers and it doesn't on others. It doesn't work on `Chrome 52` it does work on `Chrome 51` and `Chrome 53 beta`